# Translation of "invincible independence"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I wanted a phrase that means something like "invincible independence" or "undefeatable independence".

Google Translate gave me: "*invicta independentiae*".

I just wanted to check that that seems grammatically correct. Is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not (at least, I think).

> *independentia invicta*

would be better. Remember, adjectives must match the nouns they modify in **gender**, **number**, and **case**.